# Parsed information that I'm trying to use to update another list (Python via replit)

Tags: python

I'm starting with a "text-type" file that I'm parsing (line by line) into lists that I'm manipulating.  I'm using the lists: inputs, gateInput, gateOutput, gateType, nodeLevel, and gateList to manipulate the data as I need it.  Presently, all the information parsed out correctly and I'm currently at an impasse.

I'm taking from a list of lists (gateInput) and I want to compare the contents with (inputs) to see if all the gateInputs are inputs.  If so, I'm wanting to update the nodeLevel to reflect as such.

```
def compareInputs(x):
    count = 0
    for l in x:
        for i in inputs:
            if l in i:
                print(x)
```

#---------------------------------------

```
for (g,h) in zip(gateList,nodeLevel):
    for (a,b) in zip(gateOutput,gateInput):
        if g == a:
            compareInputs(b)
```

The two for loops and an if are what I'm using to get to where I send the item (b) to the function compareInputs.  In compareInputs, I'm able to get things to cycle through, but it compares (lets say 'a') to every item list.  Lets say that the len(list) is 3.  So it compares 'a' three times, then goes to 'b' 3 times and then 'c' three times.

What I'm attempting to see is if list is comprised of only elements from inputs = ['a', 'b', 'c'].  I do understand that this is a lot.  It's not easy for me.  I have a lot of things working against me.  Any help would be appreciated.

Me printing in my function was to see if I'm getting the correct information to where I need it, and I am.  Just need help with how to compare it to get the answer I'm after.

sample data

```
['c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
['a', 'b', 'c']
["a'", 'b', 'c']
["a'", 'b', 'c']
['c']
['a', "b'"]
['a']
['b']
['a', 'b', "c'"]
['a', 'b', "c'"]
["b'", 'c']
['b', "c'"]
```

These would be the component 'l' that is taken from 'x'.  'x' being a list of lists.

Comment: Please fix the indentation. Which loops are supposed to be inside the function?

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable, it's the name of a built-in class.

Comment: Why don't you use `h` anywhere?

Comment: You probably want something like `if any(l in i for i in inputs): print(l)

Comment: Please post sample data and the desired output.

Comment: the indentations were fine...sorry that you couldn't see the separate loops.  I've edited it otherwise.  I'll post the sample data, but I'm unsure what I'm trying to see other than 'a','b' exist in gateInput.

Comment: The lines after `def compareInputs(x):` needs to be indented to be inside the function.

Comment: My apologies.  They are fine on my code, I suppose when I copied and pasted here is was goofed up.

Comment: Your code uses 5 lists: `gateList`, `nodeLevel`, `gateOutput`, `gateInput`, and `inputs`. Which of those is the sample data you posted?

Comment: that data is from gateInput.  gateOutput and gateInput are the same size.  gateList and nodeLevel are the same size.  inputs is the smallest at this point.  My goal is that I'm going to update nodeLevel based off of some information that I would be receiving from what I was trying to do.

Comment: I don't care what the sizes are. I want you to post actual data and the desired result, so we can understand the relationship.

Comment: If you want to know if a list is comprised only of elements from `inputs`, use `if all(i in inputs for i in x)`

Comment: the sample data that I provided is the actual data that I'm working with.  I'll try the "if all" thing. thank you.

Comment: You still haven't clearly explained what all this code is supposed to do. All you said is that you don't want to cycle over every element. But that's what nested loops do.